# 0 opacity in css and what to use jquery mouseenter to change opacity and size

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create a div and set the opacity to 0 with css(background, color, border) so completely invisible and the whole thing will only work if js enabled. There is another div next to it, and want to use jQuery to change the opacity to 1 and change it size. If possible with fadeIn fadeOut.

So far I didn't get far, still couldn't even change the opacity, although a researched it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showCaseWD").hover(function(){
        $("#wdShow").css({color:rgba(0,0,0,1.0)});
    });
});
```

Comment: `div:hover { visibility: hidden }`? That won't give you the transitions, but gives you a "transparent" element.

Comment: `.css({color:rgba(0,0,0,1.0)})` should be `.css({color:"rgba(0,0,0,1.0)"})` or just `.css('color','rgba(0,0,0,1.0)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.. You'll have to use a css transition if you don't want the opacity change to be abrupt. css 'color' refers to the colour of the text inside the div. So if you want to change the opacity of the whole div, just use css 'opacity' property.

```
#wdShow {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.2s opacity ease;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showCaseWD").on('mouseenter', function() {
        $("#wdShow").css('opacity', '1');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#wdShow'){
      'opacity':0.8,
      'transition':'0.3s opacity linear'
    });

    $("#showCaseWD").hover(function(){
        $("#wdShow").css({
           'background-color':'rgb(0,0,0,1.0)'
    });

});
```

Comment: Your javascript is malformed and broken.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/1xopc6bq/1/.

```
$("#showCaseWD").mouseenter
```

To make a div invisible you can use opacity, background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); or visibility:hidden;

Also I recommend to read http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: Thanks, that actually works. Can i put a timer on this to make it look like it fades in? Also I want a transition effect on it to make it bigger. Example first in .5s it will appear in 0.3 opacity then after in 1s it will transform to opacity 1 and change the width and height to bigger

Comment: Instead of css you should use fadeTo(time, value);